# Ajax : return null value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a form to insert user. I use POST method and stored procedure. The `ReturnStatus` and `ReturnMessage` will be automatically called based on the data inserted.

I encountered some error as the ajax return `null` value before the data is inserted. But when the form is filled and submitted its work completely fine and managed to display the result of the successful operation.

This is my code:

**php**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    $UserNm=$_POST["UserNm"];
    $UserId=$_POST["UserId"];
    $UserPwd=$_POST["UserPwd"];

    $stmt = odbc_exec(
        $conn,
        "CALL UserInsert (
            '$UserNm',
            '$UserId',
            '$UserPwd',)"
        );

    if (!$stmt) {
        "Error : " . odbc_errormsg();
    }

    if ($stmt) {
        if (odbc_fetch_row($stmt)) {
            $ReturnStatus=odbc_result($stmt,'ReturnStatus');
            $ReturnMessage=odbc_result($stmt,'ReturnMessage');
        }

        if(isset($ReturnStatus) && $ReturnStatus==1) {
            $ReturnMessage=odbc_result($stmt,'ReturnMessage');
        } 
    }
}

echo json_encode($ReturnMessage);

?>
```

**script**

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
      url: "insert_sp.php",
      dataType: "json", 
      success: function(data){ 
        alert(data.test);
      }
    });
</script>
```

Please help me. Thank you :)

Comment: Question not clear..........can you edit it with better explainination

Comment: what's the output of `json_encode($ReturnMessage)` ?

Comment: Updated my question @ Naincy

Comment: Null but when the data is submitted, the successful `ReturnMessage` is displayed @HassanAhmed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check, if your `$ReturnMessage` Object is UTF-8 encoded, since json_encode only handles UTF-8 encoded data.
You can test the encoding with http://php.net/manual/de/function.mb-detect-encoding.php and change it with http://php.net/manual/de/function.utf8-encode.php

@see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php:

> All string data must be UTF-8 encoded.

Add this line right before your `json_encode` line:

```
$ReturnMessage = utf8_encode ( $ReturnMessage );
```

Comment: The `$ReturnMessage` return `ASCII` when I test the encoding. I'm kind of confuse on how to change them. Could you possibly show me how? @Paladin

Comment: Thank you :) .The null is gone and is replaced by `" "` . I then changed the position of the `json_encode` inside `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` and they work perfectly fine now.

Answer (score 1):

you are checking for POST request type:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

while your ajax send a `GET` request, read more about how to [POST](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) using ajax and jquery.

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
      url: "insert_sp.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: {submit: 'true'},
      success: function(response) {
        // while you are expecting a json response
        // so you will need to decode it .
        var data = JSON && JSON.parse(response) || $.parseJSON(response);
        alert(data);
      }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The `null` value is still there. @HassanAhmed . The documentation is confusing but I'll look into it. Thank you :)

Comment: change this line `"Error : " . odbc_errormsg();` to be `echo "Error : " . odbc_errormsg();`; and check if there is any errors , and add this to ajax success callback `alert(response);` and check your console .

Comment: There is no error. The `$ReturnMessage` is displayed replacing the null when submitted.  But I can't still get rid of the `null` at the beginning when the data is not yet submitted. @HassanAhmed